# Drupal.settings.ckeditor is undefind in CKEditor module

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

I have installed CKeditor module as per the guidelines of ckeditor README.txt file.
But in neither text area ckeditor is loading.
When I inspected in firebug it shows me following error

> Error: TypeError: Drupal.settings.ckeditor is undefined Source File:
>   localhost/drupal7/sites/all/modules/contrib/ckeditor/includes/ckeditor.utils.js
>   Line: 5

I am wondering is there any problem in configuration?

I have installed and configured CKEditor module previously many times but I haven't encountered such type of error

Comment: Are you installed on same environment as before ? Maybe system is unable to read from directory (file permissions) ?

Comment: Yes. I have enabled in previous Drupal 7 sites. In same Wamp setup, every thing is same

Comment: Try to check server php log if there is an error... or simply try to wipe out and reinstall module... Also there may be another module causing that, see if there is difference there btween this and your other setups

Comment: I reinstalled it three times but no clue.

Comment: It is a JavaScript error. It might be problem with jQuery update module or conflict with some other JavaScript driven module, or settings.

Comment: @HoverFusion: thanks for giving your time. One module which i installed was creating bottleneck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got a clue. I had enabled [HeadJs](http://drupal.org/project/headjs) module for improving jquery loading time. This module was creating bottleneck. Just uninstalled this module and work like a charm.